# Autoencoder Conv1D Wrong shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a model based on a number of txt. file with 2623 lines of numbers. The model is as follows:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(2623,1), name='input')

x = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False)(input_img)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(16, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(2623,1))(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(16,3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(2623,1))(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
encoded = MaxPooling1D(2, padding='same')(x)


x = Conv1D(16,3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(2623,1))(encoded)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x)
x = Conv1D(16,3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(2623,1))(x)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x)
x = Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same', use_bias=False, input_shape=(2623,1))(x)  #input_shape=(30, 1))
x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)  
x = UpSampling1D(2)(x)
decoded = Conv1D(3, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same', use_bias=False,input_shape=(2623,1))(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')


x = Input(shape=(16, 300), name="input")
h = x
h = Conv1D(filters=300, kernel_size=16,
             activation="relu", padding='same', name='Conv1',input_shape=(2623,1))(h)
h = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=16, name='Maxpool1')(h)
```

Whenever i try to fit the model with the following code i get an error saying: 
**Error when checking target: expected conv1d_283 to have shape (2624, 1) but got array with shape (2623, 1)**

I tried different padding and setting the input space smaller but it does not seem to work. I do not get the error because whatever i do in the end i have an error for different dimensions. Any ideas?

```
history = autoencoder.fit(train, train,
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=256,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(test, test))
```

Comment: Check your train dimensions.They must have shape (2624,1).Or, change input_shape according to your train shape

Comment: my train shape is (1020, 2623) which basically is 1020 txt files with 2623 lines each so it is the same i guess

Comment: Can you print and tell the shape of `encoded`? Also there are multiple `Conv1D`s. Check which of them is giving the error.

Comment: Hmm running encoded.shape i get: TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(328), Dimension(16)])

Comment: Decoded.shape() gives: TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(2624), Dimension(3)]) on the other hand. I think this is the problem

Comment: @powersiganospowersiganos:Change all of your `(2623,1)` in the code with `(2624,3)` and it should work.

Comment: I still get : Error when checking input: expected input to have shape (2624, 3) but got array with shape (2623, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the help. In the end adding a croplayer in the end did the trick, i.e:

```
x = Cropping1D(cropping=(0, 1))(x) # Crop nothing from input but crop 1 elemnt from the end
```